# React router path: making optional value inside path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Consider the following two react route paths:

1. `/site/my/photos/:id`
2. `/site/photos/:id`

I would like the `'my'` inside first path to be optional.

How can I make it optional (probably something to do with `?` symbol), and how can I then retrieve if the `my` is present or not in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array of paths to the Route from react-router-dom, for example:

```
<Route path={["/site/my/photos/:id", "/site/photos/:id"]} component={MyComponent} />
```

Comment: How can I then retrieve inside the component if the `my` is present or not?

Comment: props.location.pathname.includes("my")

Answer (score 1):

i think you should define two routes with same component like below :

```
<Route path="/site/my/photos/:id" component={MyComponent} />

<Route path="/site/photos/:id" component={MyComponent} />
```

Comment: How can I then retrieve if `my` is present or not?

Comment: props.location.pathname.includes("my")